# JavaScript onchange select binding issue

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I cannot seems to select the correct keywords in Google to find this answer.

I am creating a series of functions within a class to handle select box changes.  Here is a very simple example of how the JavaScript is laid out:

```
function example(n) {
  this.name = n;
}

example.prototype.setChange(i) {
  var c = document.getElementById('test' + i );
  for ( var x = 0; x < 10; x++
    c.options[0] = new Option(x, x);
  c.change = this.doChange;
}

example.prototype.doChange() {
  alert(this.name);
}
```

Everything works find until I try to access 'this'.  When `doChange` is called, this is the actual select html object instead of the class.  Because this is an event, I cannot use `.call(this)` to enforce the proper bindings.

Comment: This code isn't even syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loose your `this` by doing `this.doChange`. Use something like

```
function example(n) {
 this.name = n;

  var self = this;
  this.doChange = function () {
    alert(self.name);
 }
}
```